# Handling non understandable behaviour of Java date formats.

Tags: java, date

As I am not expert in handling of dates in java but I am unable to understand this behaviour.
Here is my code

```
Date from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("05/07/2013");
System.out.println(from);
```

which gave me this output

`Sat Jul 05 00:07:00 PKT 2013`

And this is 2nd another code snippet

```
Date from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("05/07/2013");
System.out.println(from);
```

which gave me this output:
`Sat Jan 05 00:07:00 PKT 2013`

Now the thing which is considerable is format. 
This format `dd/MM/yyyy` which have `MM` gave me correct output but this format `dd/mm/yyyy` which have small `mm` gave me wrong output (always give `jan` in month).I read the doc where it is mentioned that samll m is for minutes and capital M is for month
 My question is Can I never use small m here? if no , then why it is giving the result and on which basis it is giving `jan` everytime 
I know this is a basic question but after searching and after not finding any understandable thing , I posted it.Thanks

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please care to comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("05/07/2013");
```

that `mm` in your format is for minutes. `MM` is for month.

Those formatting placeholders are fixed. small m is always for minutes. And it's January because this is the default Month value.

Answer (score 4):

mm is for minutes so you do not have any month in your date. Thus, I guess that the month is initialized to 0 (Jan)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not fail is because by default the formatter is lenient. If you want it to fail then `setLenient(false)` on the formatter object.

Although I do not think it will fail in your case as in your example it will read 07 as minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
Date from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("05/07/2013");
```

the simple mm is for minutes therefore i think the value for month is assumed to be 0 so it gives Jan as the default value so use MM for month.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it comes from `calendar.clear()` which will point to 1 Jan 1970. Then it adds you parsed data = 2013 years (YY), 5 days (dd) and 7 minutes (mm). Use `MM` for month